# Why is it that the collection of all odd permutations of ${1,2,3,...,n}$ do not form a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I have a theorem in my Abstract Algebra book (9.20 in "A first Course in Abstract Algebra, 7th edition) that states:

If $n \geq 2$, then the collection of all even permutations of $\{{1,2,3,...,n\}}$ forms a subgroup of order $n!/2$ of the symmetric group $S_n$

But apparently the odd permutations are not?

There is no real explanation as to why this is, I was wondering if someone could help me out with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Odd + Odd = Even

Comment: It might be worth noting that the inverse of an odd permutation actually is odd, so even though they don't form a group, they at least have some property.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to see it's not a subgroup is to realize that the identity is an even permutation.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same reason why the even integers form a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$, but the odd integers don't.